# IntelliJ Idea 12 worksheet + sbt + Scala -- error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I run a worksheet in IntelliJ Idea 12 (sbt plugin, Scala project), I've got an error of:

```
> Failed to initialize compiler: class scala.reflect.BeanInfo not found.
  ** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
  ** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
  ** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

Everything what has to be set up, is setup: sbt, dependencies, etc, that is if run this project using sbt command line (compile, run), it will run successfully.

Of course, I ran `sbt gen-idea`.

What do I do?

Comment: IntelliJ 12 has caused me all sorts of problems (not this specific one, but lots of others).  My solution, unfortunately, is to just use sbt from cmdline instead.

Comment: @sberry, is it possible to use kind of a worksheet in a command line?

Comment: It would appear not.  At least, I can't find a way to do it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I created a *new* Scala project with IntelliJ IDEA and set the Scala home to the manually downloaded and unpacked Scala folder for Scala 2.10.2.

Now you can set the Scala compiler in the real project:
Switch to the real project, open the project structure settings and then Modules | your module name | Scala | compiler library. Switch to your new version.
Set the language level to 2.10.